# Vertical alignment of binary relation symbol

Tags: vertical-alignment, relation-symbols

As far as I understand, binary relations like $\Vdash$ are (vertically) centered to properly fit uppercase letters. For example, $A \Vdash B$ looks fine.

I use this symbol in a context where it is always surrounded by parentheses or alike, more specifically: $\cdots \rangle \Vdash ( \cdots$.
Both \rangle and ( go "a bit higher than A" and "a bit lower than g" and altogether $\Vdash$ is noticeably **not** centered but slightly moved upwards. It is particularly striking as $\rangle$ makes the vertical center clearly visible.

[image]

I *could* probably make a new command that pushes \Vdash slightly downwards, using a handpicked offset. Which would most probably break when for some reason the font size changes...

Is there any decent fix for this?

**Update**: obligatory MWE and picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \cdots \rangle \vdash ( \cdots \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If memory serves, `\vdash` and friends came from logic, and, rather than being centered vertically, they are positioned on the baseline.  This (for many fonts) positions the horizontal component a bit higher than (say) a minus sign.  The mechanism for adjusting this is given in the answer, but the reason for the existing position may add to understanding the need,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (ab)use `\mathop`, which centres its argument (as long as it is a single token) on the math axis, and make the resulting atom a `\mathrel` again:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\cvdash}{\mathrel{\mathop\vdash}}

\begin{document}

$a \cvdash b + c$

\end{document}
```

[image]